# How to include executable code snippet in multiple Bash shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to a code snippet that reads a properties file and defines variables in multiple other scripts, to avoid coding the same in each of my scripts.

For example, I want to be able to include the execution like below, in many scripts, after some initial work from each of the scripts, that have no relationship with each other

```sh
    while IFS='=' read -r key value
    do
      echo "key ${key}"
      if [[ ${key} =~ ^# ]]; then
        echo "comment line ${key},  skipping....."
        continue
      fi
      eval ${key}=\${value}
      echo "key ${key} :  value ${value}"
    done < kafka-env-parameters.txt
```

Since the parameter file and the defined variables will be same for multiple scripts, I want to avoid adding this snippet in every shellscript.

Is it possible to do so, in shell script? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Could you just do something like `set -x; source kafka-env-parameters.txt; set +x`?

Comment: Define a function, put it in a lib file and source it in each script?

Comment: If you don't need the variables `key` and `value` to persist after the code snippet has been executed, put it into a separate shell script file and run it as a command.

Comment: I do need it to persist - it defines the variables from the properties file - that would be common for many scripts - it defines kafka server info and and that info is used in the kafka command line commands that will be executed from each script - for example - one script is CREATE TOPICS, the grant ACLs etc.  I am just trying to avoid adding same code to multiple scripts, if I could avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function with this code, place it within a lib file, let's say *readParams.lib*[^1].

```
     readParamFile () {
      while IFS='=' read -r key value
      ....
      ....
      done < $1
    }
```

Then source (include) the function code with `source readParams.lib`
and invoke it from your different scripts, passing the path of the file to be read as argument to the function: `readParamFile kafka-env-parameters.txt`

```
    <some code>   
    source readParams.lib 
    readParamFile kafka-env-parameters.txt 
    <some code>
    <some code>
```

[^1]: Thanks to Charles Duffy for the correction about functions declaration syntax.

Comment: And I would call it like this `readParamFile kafka-env-parameters.txt` from inside my shell script ?  Thanks

Comment: Note that `function funcname() {` merges the ksh function syntax `function funcname {` and the POSIX-standard function syntax `funcname() {` in a way that makes your code incompatible with _both_ ksh and POSIX, while not providing the special behavior that `function` enabled in legacy ksh. See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete (there are references in both first and third tables).

Comment: @adbdkb, correct, _after_ sourcing the file, you can call any function that file defines. (But... really, do take the `function` keyword off; it makes the code gratuitously incompatible while adding no benefit. `source libraryname` can also be replaced with `. libraryname` for an additional compatibility benefit, but at least `source` is more readable; `function` buys no advantage at all).

Comment: This worked. I was able to put the function in a separate file and was able to source it in multiple scripts.  Thanks. Thanks also to @CharlesDuffy for giving detailed information about function keyword usage while defining a function in bash script